# Different @JsonProperty config for READ and WRITE on same field?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-annotations

I have a class (which cannot be modified) like

```
public class Standing {

    private Integer positionNumber;
    private String positionText;
    private BigDecimal points;
    ..
}
```

When deserializing I get data like:

```
{
    "position": "1",
    "points": 10
}
```

As I cannot modify the `Standing` class I have a mix-in like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = StandingSanitizer.class)
public abstract class StandingMixIn {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    Integer positionNumber;

    @JsonProperty(value = "position", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    String positionText;
}
```

As the received json does not have `positionNumber` and `positionText` fields I use the `@JsonPropery` annotations.

With `Access.READ_ONLY` I simply ignore the `positionNumber` field.

And with `@JsonProperty(value = "position", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` on the `positionText` field I make sure it's populated with the `position` field from the json during deserialization.

This works well during deserialization.

Note the `StandingSanitizer` sets the `positionNumber`. This as the received `position` value can be non-number values like `DSQ` in which case the `positionNumber` field will be `null`.

But when serializing I want to output all 3 fields from the `Standing` class like:

```
{
    "positionText": "1",
    "positionNumber": 1,
    "points": 10
}
```

But because of `@JsonProperty(value = "position", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` on the `positionText` field it is not serialized unfortunately.

In theory I would like to do have something like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = StandingSanitizer.class)
public abstract class StandingMixIn {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    Integer positionNumber;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @JsonProperty(value = "position", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    String positionText;
}
```

where I could use different `@JsonProperty` annotation for both READ and WRITE.

But this is not possible as duplicate `@JsonProperty` annotations on a field are not allowed; and as far as I could see there is no support for repeatable annotations.

Is there any other solution to solve this?

One thing I can think of is to have 2 `ObjectMapper` instances, with 2 different `StandingMixIns`; 1 for deserializing and 1 for serializing. But I would prefer to keep having 1 `ObjectMapper` instance, so using 2 would be a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the getters and setters to get that extra customization. The get will act as READ and the set as WRITE. Note that you don't need the access properties or the field level annotation:

```
    public abstract class StandingMixIn {
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        Integer positionNumber;
        
        // No annotation on the field
        String positionText;

        @JsonProperty(value = "positionText")
        public String getPositionText() {
            return positionText;
        }

        @JsonProperty(value = "position")
        public void setPositionText(String positionText) {
            this.positionText = positionText;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Franjavi, you are indeed right I should use annotations on the getters/setters and not on the field only. I was to focussed on only using the fields as my mix-in classes are written in Groovy with implicit getters/setters.

I slimmed down the class a bit more to just:

```
    public abstract class StandingMixIn {

        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        Integer positionNumber;
        
        @JsonProperty(value = "positionText")
        public abstract String getPositionText();

        @JsonProperty(value = "position")
        public abstract void setPositionText(String positionText);
    }
```

(removing the `positionText` completely and using abstract methods)